# How to enable a child component to make changes to a parent's appbar?

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

Imagine the following scenario - the app has a global Scaffold with a global AppBar. The body of the Scaffold is one of many app components. Each component would have the global appbar render differently and also have access to the appbar's TabController (so that listeners can be attached to it).

The easiest way to implement this would be for each of the pages to have their own Scaffold with an AppBar and hide the AppBar from the main app Scaffold. This, however, would break transitions/animations, because instead of just the page fading in, the appbar would also fade in (since its part of the page), which would look very weird.

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and would appreciate some help. I've tried using Redux and changing the appearance of the global appbar depending of a value in the Redux state, but I still have the issue with the TabController of the main Scaffold being inaccessible from any of the child pages.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method that I've always followed is to just keep each page have its own Scaffold and its own AppBar. It's because of this context being passed from one Scaffold to another is when the AppBar knows there is a navigation change.

I don't think the page transition animation applies to the AppBar, but even if it does, there's a workaround to that. You can write your own FadePageTransition so you don't notice the AppBar shifting, plus an added bonus of it looking really cool.

If you do want to go with the one Scaffold, global AppBar approach, it could be done but seems a bit messy. You can connect a provider to it and change the current state through that, but it is messy for two reasons: 1) a provider stream is always being sent to the AppBar and 2) you would need to set the value in the provider every time to push a new screen so as to notify the AppBar about changes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah it felt messy to me too, but I thought that the transition always depends on the actual hierarchy of components and that I had to have a global AppBar if I wanted it to stay static while pages transition. Can you elaborate on the FadePageTransition? It would allow me to have the AppBar stay static?

Comment: The AppBar animating is pretty obvious because I have a ScaleOutwards type of animation and so the Scaffold Bottom stays static (part of the global Scaffold), but the content and the AppBar scales outwards from the center which looks weird.